# Group array of lat/lng coordinates together on map

Tags: javascript, titanium, coordinates

I'm trying to compare an array of lat/lng coordinates for a map to see if any "cluster" or group together. I want to remove the ones that are too close together so if there are 4-5 stacking on top of each other on a map, it wil only show 1 until you zoom in a bit more, and then it will recalculate all of them again.

I've tried comparing the array to itself, but it doesn't seem to give consistant results. Has anyone attempted something like this before?

JSON Example:

```
[
{
    Latitude = "44.033843";
    Longitude = "-79.48865499999999";
},
{
    Latitude = "44.033843";
    Longitude = "-79.48865499999999";
}]
```

Comment: Whats the data structure of your lat/long list? Is it an array of objects, each containing a .lat and .lon for example.

Comment: You can check out [MarkerClustererPlus](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries) (built for Google maps) for some ideas. Google maps has a built in cluster utility, but this one is more efficient.

Comment: @MasterAM I can't use Google Maps. I'm using the Titanium framework, so I'm looking for a more "generic" solution. Otherwise I'd use exactly that.

Comment: @techfoobar It's a JSON object. I'll update my question above with an example.

Comment: What do you mean by "comparing the array to itself"? Show us the code you tried. Also, your JSON is invalid; you probably want square brackets.

Comment: I've updated the above example with square brackets

Answer (score 3):

Iterate the nodes and for a zoom level only display those that are beyond a set distance from each other. The haversine formula is simple enough to implement: example in JS here.

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

For the efficiency aspect, you probably don't want to calculate the entire list against the temporary list on every iteration so as a first level declutter a simple rounding works (every degree being ~60 miles from each other) ... start with rounding to the nearest 5 degrees, then 1, then 10ths, 100ths, etc as you zoom in. Ordering these lists and pulling unique array values first - then calculating distances from the resultant list.

There are certainly many other algorithms to do it - but at some point you have to calculate distances.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this assumes you're happy to fudge things a little bit, and instead of worrying about the actual distance between points on the globe, you look at the "Manhattan" distance of their lat/long coordinates.  It depends on how precise you need to be, and whether you have points near the Earth's poles.  But for most practical purposes this assumption should be fine.

Suppose your desired precision is one decimal place.  Then I would just iterate through the array, building up a has where the keys are the rounded coordinates and the values are arrays of lat/long pairs which round to the corresponding key.

```
hash = Hash.new
latLongArray.each { |point|
  key = [point.lat.round(1), point.long.round(1)]
  hash[key] = Array(hash[key]) + [point.lat, point.long]
}
```

This way you have them clustered, and you can in fact just put markers at the coordinates given by the keys themselves.